# How to make new line with vim language?

Tags: concatenation, newline, vim

I want to know how to implement a new line (`\n`) in vim language; without using regex.

When i use this instruction, the result is :

> ^@

But no new line...

Thanks

Comment: By "vim language" do you mean "vim script"?

Comment: Yes i mean in a script .vim

Comment: with "\r" i have ^M which is display.

Comment: @Elyos Don’t make us guess how exactly you are trying to add a new line. If you use `:s//\n` `\r` was a right advice. If you use `setline()`/`append()` you should use a list of lines. When asking such question always include exact steps you do to get unexpected result (`^@` in this case). Without context “when I use this instruction” is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, what exactly you want, but to put a new line in the buffer, simply enter `:put =`

Alternatively, you can use `:call append(1, 'foobar')`